# Is it possible to stop all network traffic from python program?

Tags: python

Is it possible to stop from a python code all network traffic made by my computer?
If yes, how?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to do this for testing, I recommend using [pytest-socket](https://github.com/miketheman/pytest-socket)

---

If you're looking to do this for real, you can try using the [WMI interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/WmiSdk/wmi-tasks--networking)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your machine, you could use NetLimiter to block the networking access for a single process. On Unix you could do something like setting up the iptables to drop all packages coming from Python.
You can run a python script in sandmode using the answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/212199, if the script is not running already.

If you gave more detail, a more detailed answer could be provided. 
From what you're saying, the best answer is: "Cut the cable".